# Java Inputstream not read entirely

Tags: java, image, file, inputstream

I have a stream of a picture (currently a png, but it could be something else), and I want to convert this as a file.
Problem : The stream is not entierely read:
The initial picture from which the stream comes is about 20KB, and the finale file is 16 B
Here is my code:

```
...
    fileImageOutput = new FileImageOutputStream(_templateFile);        

    int read = 0;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

    while ((read = imageStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
        fileImageOutput.write(bytes, 0, read);
    }
}
catch(IOException ioe)
{
    throw ioe;
}
finally
{
    if(fileImageOutput!=null)
        fileImageOutput.close();
    if(imageStream!=null)
        imageStream.close();
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Nicolas

Comment: Can you insert the code where you create your input stream? Also have  you done any checking to see what those 16 bytes are and see if they line up with the first 16 bytes of the image file?

Comment: first read the contents of the file and print in screen and open the file which is used check the difference in contents

Comment: Call flush on your stream before closing it

Comment: @Stefoan close flushes too

Comment: Even if it wasn't flushing the stream the buffer is only 1kb not ~20kb.

Comment: Something is amiss with your imageStream. Can you tell us a bit more about it? Could it be that whatever source fills it is the one that isn't properly flushed?

Comment: What is FileImageOutputStream? You want to use a normal FileInputStream.

Comment: Debug the read loop and see what it's actually reading (or at least, how many bytes it read on each iteration)

Comment: I meant FileOutputStream above, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

While you're writing to a file, you should use FileOutputStream instead of FileImageOutputStream.. the writer writes bytes, whatever they are. It would be more clear, if we saw the entire code in your try/catch block.

```
...
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileOutputStream(_templateFile));    
int read;
while ((read = imageStream.read()) != -1) {
  writer.write(read);
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers.
Actually, I found the problem : I mixed both ways to load the picture, and both used the inputstream. Since I started with the first one, I assumed this changed its index, and the second read of the stream started at the end. Whatever, I deleted the second read, and it works now!

Thanks however

Niko